# Glimpse and RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I am trying to follow [Scott Hanselman's example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek5DebuggingASPNETMVCApplicationsWithGlimpse.aspx) on using glimpse to trace an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

```
Public Function SomeAction(id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim traceid = Guid.NewGuid.ToString

    Trace.TraceInformation(traceid & " " & 
        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fffffff") & " action start")

    ...

    Trace.TraceInformation(traceid & " " & 
        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fffffff") & " some other traces")

    Return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction", New With {.id = id})
End Function
```

As you can see, in my case, at the end of the function, I redirect to another action and in "AnotherAction", glimpse doesn't show the traces that I have written during "SomeAction".

Is it possible to see the traces that I wrote to the action before redirect with glimpse?

BTW glimpse v.0.82

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endy,

You can view past requests using Glimpse's remote tab.

Click the remote tab, and select the "Launch" link on the right. This will then show you the list of requests made from that client over time.

From that listing you can then click the "Launch" link for a given request to view all of the Glimpse information (including logging) for that past request.  This is noted in Glimpse by changing URL changing and the string "(Remote)" showing up in the top left corner/status area.

We have been working on our documentation and there should be more information available about this tab very soon.

Comment: Got it, thanks! The "from last" column is very nice, I don't have to maintain my own timer.

Comment: @nikmd23 the history tab doesn't provide information about the requests before the last Response.Redirect